# Karma unit test for the typescript method which is taking NgForm as parameter

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write unit test for method:

```
public addCred:boolean=true;
public credName:any;

public addMachineCredential(credentialForm: NgForm) {
    this.addCred = true;
    this.credName = credentialForm.value.name;
}
```

In my test class:

```
  it('should add machine credential', () => {
    var machineCredentialForm: NgForm = new NgForm(null, null);
    machineCredentialForm.controls['name'].setValue('name');
    machineCredentialForm.controls['username'].setValue('username');
    machineCredentialForm.controls['password'].setValue('password');
    component.addMachineCredential(machineCredentialForm);
    expect(component.addCred).toBe(true);
    expect(component.credName).toBe("name");
  });
```

I am getting error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'setValue' of undefined`

How to test function "addMachineCredential" ?

Comment: you're trying to set properties of controls, when there is no controls

Comment: How to define control?

Comment: I was investigating that.. and I think you're using a template driven form, and you're trying to test.. doesn't work, for that you should use reactive forms, then, you can define a formgroup on the component and test.. Else.. you need to add components to your `NgForm` because there aren't any on that test.. just an empty instance of `NgForm`

Answer (score 0):

To be able to unit test the module you should use ReactiveForms instead of Template driven forms as mentioned in the comment.. I did a refactoring (and came up with an example based on the snippet you posted...) and came up with a possible solution:

So, this is one way you can refactor your code to make it work.

your component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-unit-test',
  template: `
  <p>Works</p>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./unit-test.component.css']
})
export class UnitTestComponent {
  public addCred: boolean = true;
  public credName: any;

  form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl('', [])
  });

  constructor() {}

  public addMachineCredential(credentialForm: FormGroup) {
    this.addCred = true;
    this.credName = credentialForm.controls.name.value;
  }
}
```

your spec file:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { UnitTestComponent } from './unit-test.component';

fdescribe('UnitTestComponent', () => {
  let component: UnitTestComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<UnitTestComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [UnitTestComponent],
      imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UnitTestComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should add machine credential', () => {
    component.form.controls.name.setValue('name');
    component.addMachineCredential(component.form);
    expect(component.addCred).toBe(true);
    expect(component.credName).toBe('name');
  });
});
```

Don't forget that your component module has to declare ReactiveFormsModule, so..

your module:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { UnitTestComponent } from './Questions/unit-test/unit-test.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UnitTestComponent,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Hope it helps.